# Brakes to low one year after replacing calipers

Tags: disk-brakes

2002 Highlander Brakes very low to floor. Work find just low. Had new Calipers put on one year ago 1313 miles ago.What should be replaced???

Comment: The first hing you need to do is check the brake fluid level, what is it at?

Comment: Do you ever use the parking brakes?  I've seen that can be a part of the rear drum auto-adjustment.  Try appying the parking brakes fully and then the regular brakes.  Make a series of forward and reverse stops using the parking brake between to try and allow them to auto adjust.

Comment: Parking brake not working  Around 300.00  to fix